# When I create .desktop files, they don't get found by Trusty's Dash

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

Magnifier not found by Trusty's Dash though Manage Launcher (both variants) are.

I've tried creating Magnifier.desktop both with Manage Launcher, Manage Launcher (Administrator) & Arronax.

```
root@JohnDesktop:/home/john# ls -l /usr/share/applications/Ma*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 142 May  7 15:35 /usr/share/applications/Magnifier.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 322 Oct  1  2013 /usr/share/applications/Manage Launcher (Administrator).desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 281 Oct  1  2013 /usr/share/applications/Manage Launcher.desktop
```

Comment: I've found that if I use my own app named Maintain Desktop Configuration Files (written in Gambas using apps from Desktop-file-utils & gnome-panle packages) to install a .desktop file from one of my home folders, then the Dash can find it. However, if I use a Terminal cp command then it cannot.
PS I think due to latest Trusty s/w updates, that none of my apps (including standard Trusty installed ones) are available from the Dash!

Comment: This issue (of no apps found in dash) was reported in Ubuntu Forums in 2011. The problem appears to be a corrupted .cache. I removed $HOME/.cache and after a log out/log in, dash went back to its normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

How about making them executable? You can also create launchers in **~/.local/share/applications**

Comment: Just tried that. No success. Also tried putting it in ~/.local/share/applications: no success. It's almost as though there's a file somewhere which specifies which desktop files the Dash will regard as apps. PS Creating desktop files in Precise used to work fine.

Comment: Hmm, it works fine for me. Could you post contents of your .desktop files?

Comment: I've had issues with ~/.local/share/applications... You could make it accessible throughout the whole system (and possibly getting it in the dash) by placing it in /usr/share/applications

Comment: Contents of Magnifier.desktop:
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Hidden=false
Terminal=false
Icon=/usr/share/magnifier/icon3.png
Name=Magnifier
Exec=/usr/bin/vmg

PS latest updates to Trusty have introduced some strange bugs e.g. no longer able to type a tilde -> |, though keyboard layout chart shows UK keyboard correctly;
gedit (in Terminal) does nothing.

Comment: Stupid question... does /usr/bin/vmg exist? Magnifier.desktop shows in Dash for me, until I set Exec to a non-existent file.

Comment: Also, try reinstalling gedit with `sudo apt-get install --purge --reinstall gedit` and pressing Super+Space (this solved keyboard issues for me :)

Comment: /usr/bin/vmg does exist. Magnifier.desktop shows as a file not as an application.

Comment: sudo apt-get install --purge --reinstall gedit allows gedit from keyboard. Super & space has brought back the tilde.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom application instead using .desktop file

1. Install gnome panel first

   `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel`
2. Create new launcher by run this following commands

   `gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new`
3. For example, i filled it out as follows:

Type: Application

Name:  MyTerminal

Command: `gnome-terminal`

Comment: Description here (optional)

Icons: I choose terminal's icons (optional)

[image: Create Launcher]

4. Click OK for completion, you're done ! Search "your_launcher_name" at dash home